# How to access the full file system in Android 7 and higher?

Tags: root-access, 7.0-nougat, file-system, android-x86

I am running Android Nougat x86.
But in Android Nougat, one of the adverse changes is the inability to even view the files. They are invisible, apparently even to root app.

I already tried root explorer in the VM. But that failed. /storage/emulated appears as empty, despite there is a directory called /storage/emulated/0.

How do I show all files to the file managers?

Update: The terminal emulator in superuser mode actually shows these hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different file manager, e.g Solid Explorer, Es File Explorer, Asus File Manager or Root Explorer.